# Data is not coming to the DataSet in eclipse Birt

Tags: eclipse, birt

[image]![enter image description here][2]I am using eclipse Birt for reporting  an application which is built is apache ofbiz. I want to report some information in a table format and want to get the output in a pdf format,that is my purpose.I am posting the class which is getting the data from the source ..

```
 public static void getReport(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    Delegator delegator = (Delegator) request.getAttribute("delegator");
    String reportType = request.getParameter("reportType");
    String compId = request.getParameter("companyId");

    List empTaskLists =  FastList.newInstance();

    //check employee position
    try {
        //use Company Id from global context
        List<GenericValue> partyList = EntityUtil.filterByDate(delegator.findByAnd("PartyRelationshipAndDetail", UtilMisc.toMap("partyIdFrom", compId)));
        //child
        for( GenericValue party : partyList) {
            GenericValue partyInfo=delegator.findByPrimaryKey("PartyAndPerson", UtilMisc.toMap("partyId", party.get("PartyId")) );
            String partyName = partyInfo.get("firstName") +" "+partyInfo.get("lastName");      

            List<GenericValue> taskList = delegator.findList("WorkEffortAndPartyAssign", EntityCondition.makeCondition(UtilMisc.toMap("partyId", party.get("partyId"), "currentStatusId", "PTS_CREATED" , "statusId", "PAS_ASSIGNED")), null, null, null, false);

            for( GenericValue task : taskList) {

                Map taskMap = FastMap.newInstance();
                String taskName=task.getString("workEffortName");

                    taskMap.put("empId", party.get("partyId"));
                    taskMap.put("empName", partyName);
                    taskMap.put("taskName", taskName);
                    taskMap.put("start", task.get("estimatedStartDate"));
                    taskMap.put("end", task.get("estimatedCompletionDate"));

                    empTaskLists.add(taskMap);
            }   


        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This class is responsible for populating the data to the birt.And Under Birt i have a dataset which is getting empty.i am posting the open and fetch script

open script

```
var compId= "DemoScrumCompany"; 
emptaskList = FastList.newInstance();

partyList = delegator.findList("PartyRelationshipAndDetail",      EntityCondition.makeCondition(UtilMisc.toList("partyIdFrom",compId)),null, null, null, false);

//child
  for( party in partyList) {
 partyName = PartyHelper.getPartyName(party, true);      
  var conds = FastList.newInstance();
  conds.add(EntityCondition.makeCondition("partyId", EntityOperator.EQUALS,   party.get("partyId")));
conds.add(EntityCondition.makeCondition("currentStatusId", EntityOperator.EQUALS, "PTS_CREATED"));
conds.add(EntityCondition.makeCondition("statusId", EntityOperator.EQUALS, "PAS_ASSIGNED"));

taskList = delegator.findList("WorkEffortAndPartyAssign", EntityCondition.makeCondition(conds), null, null, null, false);
for( task in taskList) {
    taskMap = FastMap.newInstance();
    taskName=task.get("workEffortName");
    //taskName="Task1";
    taskMap.put("empId", party.get("partyId"));
    taskMap.put("empName", partyName);
    taskMap.put("taskName", taskName);
    taskMap.put("start", task.get("estimatedStartDate"));
    taskMap.put("end", task.get("estimatedCompletionDate"));
    //taskMap.put("empId", "EMp01");
    //taskMap.put("empName", "EMP1");
    //taskMap.put("taskName", taskName);
    //taskMap.put("start", "2014-05-21");
    //taskMap.put("end", "2014-05-31");
    emptaskList.add(taskMap);
}   

 }
totalRow = 0;
countOfRow = 0;

  if (emptaskList.size()> 0 ) {
  totalRow = emptaskList.size();
}
```

fetch script

```
  if (countOfRow < emptaskList.size()-1) {

var emptaskMap =emptaskList.get(countOfRow);
row["employeeId"] = emptaskMap.get("employeeId");
row["employeeName"] = emptaskMap.get("employeeName");
row["taskName"] =emptaskMap.get("taskName");
row["startDate"] = emptaskMap.get("startDate");
row["endDate"] = emptaskMap.get("endDate");
countOfRow++;
return true;
}

return false;
```

these i have done to have the data .is it enough????.I also have a dataset which i have attached in the picture.I need the dataset to be populated with the data[image]

Comment: It is really difficult for me to understand the issue. Could you provide exactly the steps (in bullets) what you have already done?

Comment: You want to know can BIRT report use data that you provided dynamically when invoking report - not just directly from database? This can be done, but please confirm is this what you wanted to ask.

Comment: ok i am posting what i have done so far

Comment: @Miki please take a look at my edited post

Comment: Now I see that you don't have any oda-data-set tags inside your report. Why are you using table if you don't have data source? Either you want some kind of representation for your simple data either you want tabular data for which you need table and data set. Choose between.

Comment: I have the data set see i have given a screen shot